# Goodman gas burner not lighting

Tags: furnace

Goodman warm air gas furnace. Gas burner would not light.Status code light blinked continuously. Igniter glows red hot.  I cleaned flame sensor with fine grade sand paper.  Checked transformer line voltage 110 volts in and 26 volts out. Sufficient power to open the gas valve. Gas burner still did not light. I have not checked air filter but I will replace it anyway. Any ideas you may have concerning my dilemma will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the model number? Does the gas valve open?

Comment: There should be chart on the inside of the unit saying what error code the blinking represents.

Comment: Have you checked the limit switches that sit around around the burner, there can be as many as 8, also check the condesation trap to the pressure switch

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with the pressure switch on the inducer blower.

Test all sensors for continuity.

Verify the gas assembly control valve is still functional.

Comment: Verify that gas flows when the gas valve opens. Do you smell gas?

Comment: Can you light manually (cig lighter) near the valve? Is your stove level? Gas won't ignite if it's flowing *away* from the ignitor.

Answer (score 0):

I had a Goodman that had a continuous blinking light that didn't have a corresponding error code on the chart. I replaced the control board with a new one from Amazon and it fixed it.